# asp.net entity framework code first foreign key not retrieve

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to retrieve company with trades.  I have included the entites and the retrieve method. As shown, the companies are inside trades already.

```
//company entity
public class Companies
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string companyID { get; set; }
  public string companyName { get; set; }
  public bool companyMointor { get; set; }   
}

//trade entity
public class Trade
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public DateTime tradeDate { get; set; }
  public double tradePrice { get; set; }
  public int tradeQuantity  { get; set; }
  public Companies tradeCompany { get; set; }
  public int type { get; set; }

  public types tradeType 
  {
    get { return (Entities.types)type; }
    set { type = (int) value; }
  }
}

//methods to retrieve
public List<Trade> getTrade()
{
  List<Trade> trades = (from t in dbContext.trades
                        orderby t.tradeDate descending             
                        select t).ToList();
  return trades;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem, is the company variable empty? in the trades list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Include` method to eager load navigational properties.

```
public List<Trade> getTrade()
{
    List<Trade> trades=dbContext.trades.Include(t => t.tradeCompany)
      .OrderBy(t => t.tradeDate).ToList();

    return trades;
}
```

Edit: If you are using `ObjectContext` API try the following

```
public List<Trade> getTrade()
{
    List<Trade> trades=dbContext.trades.Include("tradeCompany")
      .OrderBy(t => t.tradeDate).ToList();

    return trades;
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Shares.Entities.Trade' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Companies'.

Comment: @user974459 Did you replace `tradeCompany` parameter with `Companies`?

Comment: @user974459 that is the problem. You need to give the name of the navigational property as a string. In your code you have named it as `tradeCompany`. So use that.

Comment: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: Solved.. How to put compaany id on gridview?

Answer (score 1):

change your gettrade method to have an include line:

```
//methods to retrieve 
    public List<Trade> getTrade() 
    { 
        List<Trade> trades=(from t in dbContext.trades 
                .Include("tradeCompany")
                orderby t.tradeDate descending 

                select t).ToList(); 
        return trades; 
    }
```

Comment: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Shares.Entities.Trade' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Companies'.